# Is Unfuddle reliable?

Tags: svn, git, hosting, unfuddle

I am in need of an online project management tool that includes SVN hosting as my team of developers are all remote. I stumbled on a site called Unfuddle and have read decent reviews so far. I am very protective of my code and want to make sure I keep it safe from any unwanted eyes. Has anyone used this tool and are there any better options for my startup?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't believe this is appropriate for SO, but I've heard negative things from a user of Unfuddle, primarily performance complaints. Honestly, if you have a widely distributed team it makes more sense to go with a distributed VCS such as git, mercurial or bzr. I'd recommend github.com if you go with git.

Comment: This IS appropriate for SO but OP you should reword the question so it isn't subjective. hobodave is wrong because unfuddle DOES have git. I use it and I like it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I used Unfuddle for two different projects. I found it work very well and without significant problem. If you are very worried about Unfuddle, it has an automatic backup that can either mail the backup to you or put it onto Amazon S3, which means you can restore your svn repository elsewhere if you decide you don't like the service.

Comment: To add weight: I've been using Unfuddle for nearly three years now and it has worked out very well for me. I'm on the $9/mo package.

Answer (score 4):

+1 for Unfuddle.  My only complaint currently is that they don't (yet) support Mercurial, which I would like to investigate.

Comment: [Don't hold](https://unfuddle.com/community/forums/4/topics/508c1f) [your breath](https://unfuddle.com/community/forums/4/topics/809) :)

Comment: Which is why we eventually switched to BitBucket :-).

Answer (score 2):

Unfuddle has been un-reachable/ping-able for us now for several hours today October 3rd, 2010 - no response from support@unfuddle.com and no help on forums yet :(

### Just received the note below.  ~3 hours after original email to support.

David Croswell, Oct 03 05:05 pm (UTC):
Eric,

Thanks for your email.

Please note that we are aware of this issue and are working to resolve it as quickly as possible.

I apologize for the inconvenience. If you have any other questions, please do not hesitate to let us know.

Best Regards,

David

--
David Croswell

Shortly after the "we're working on it email from David", I got another saying the issue was fixed.

Answer (score -2):

I liked Unfuddle okay, but ended up switching all of my projects to [Codaset](http://codaset.com). It feels less complicated and clumsy to me. That's mostly personal preference, of course. Both services supported the work requirements I had.

Comment: This is no longer an option. From Codaset home page: "We are very sorry, but unfortunately Codaset is no longer operating at this time, and all services have been terminated with immediate effect."